# checking datatype in an overload doesn't work for decimal

Tags: vb.net, overloading

I'm using vb.net.  I am doing some checking and scrubbing of my data when i get it from the database.  I'm using an overload but it doesn't seem to be working for decimal numbers.  Decimal numbers get treated as integers.

```
 Public Class CheckData
    Public Shared Function Check(row As DataRow, columnName As String, pDefaultValue As Decimal) As Decimal
        Dim x As Object = ReplaceDBNullAndColumnExists(row, columnName)
        Dim y As Decimal = CDec(Dempsey.fnIsNull.IsNull(x, pDefaultValue))
        Return y
    End Function
    Public Shared Function Check(row As DataRow, columnName As String, pDefaultValue As DateTime) As DateTime
        Dim x As Object = ReplaceDBNullAndColumnExists(row, columnName)
        Dim y As DateTime = Dempsey.fnIsNull.IsNull(x, pDefaultValue)
        Return y
    End Function
    Public Shared Function Check(row As DataRow, columnName As String, pDefaultValue As Integer) As Integer
        Dim x As Object = ReplaceDBNullAndColumnExists(row, columnName)
        Dim y As Integer = Dempsey.fnIsNull.IsNull(x, pDefaultValue)
        Return y
    End Function
    Public Shared Function Check(row As DataRow, columnName As String, pDefaultValue As String) As String
        Dim x As Object = ReplaceDBNullAndColumnExists(row, columnName)
        Dim y As String = Dempsey.fnIsNull.IsNull(x, pDefaultValue)
        Return y
    End Function
    Public Shared Function Check(row As DataRow, columnName As String, pDefaultValue As Boolean) As Boolean
        Dim x As Object = ReplaceDBNullAndColumnExists(row, columnName)
        Dim y As Boolean = Dempsey.fnIsNull.IsNull(x, pDefaultValue)
        Return y
    End Function
```

So if i pass in some data and the type is a string, integer, boolean or datetime it goes to the propert function.  if i pass in a decimal it goes to integer.  If i set a breakpoint on the public shared function check that is a integer function and do a

```
row.Table.Columns(columnName).DataType.Name
```

I get back - "Decimal" (doing this in the immediate window)

So my question is what have i done wrong that it doesn't take it to the decimal overload and return a decimal value.  By the way, the actual data value is 37.50.

Thanks
shannon

I use this to populate list.

```
Public Function populate(mDs As DataSet) As List(Of SR_SalaryRange_Current)
        Dim rows As DataRowCollection
        Dim drow As DataRow
        Dim oSR_SalaryRange_Current As SR_SalaryRange_Current
        Dim oSR_SalaryRange_Currents As List(Of SR_SalaryRange_Current) = New List(Of SR_SalaryRange_Current)
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        Try
            dt = mDs.Tables("SR_SalaryRange_Currents")
            rows = dt.Rows
            For Each drow In rows
                oSR_SalaryRange_Current = New SR_SalaryRange_Current
                With oSR_SalaryRange_Current
                    .tblSR_SalaryRange_CurrentID = SitePlumbing.CheckData.Check(drow, "intTblSR_SalaryRange_CurrentID", 0)
                    .EffectiveDate = SitePlumbing.CheckData.Check(drow, "dtmEffectiveDate", CDate("1/1/1900"))

                    .WorkWeekHours = SitePlumbing.CheckData.Check(drow, "decWorkWeekHours", 0)
                End With
                oSR_SalaryRange_Currents.Add(oSR_SalaryRange_Current)
            Next
        Catch ex As Exception
            ErrorMsg = "Populate Error:" & ex.InnerException.ToString
            Return oSR_SalaryRange_Currents
        End Try
        Return oSR_SalaryRange_Currents
    End Function
```

from there it goes into the checkdata that i mentioned before.  In the code above it correctly goes to an integer and a datetime when hitting the overload, just isn't doing it for the decimal.

Comment: `scrubbing of my data when i get it from the database`  But DBs have those types.  You might want to check that a single version using Generics would also work.

Answer (score 0):

A decimal is implicitly covertable into an integer so the compiler is confused if you have OPTION STRICT set to off.  You have two options:

```
1) Set OPTION STRICT to ON.  Then the compiler will not convert implicitly.
2) Pass in a decimal literal like this: 10D (i.e. there is a D on the end telling the compiler it is a decimal).
```

For example:

```
'Sub Routine 1    
public sub Test(ByVal d as decimal)

    end sub

'Sub Routine 2
    public sub Test(ByVal i as integer)

    end sub

//Client
dim d1 as decimal={Number}D 'where {number} is replaced with a number
dim d2 as decimal={Number} 'where {number} is replaced with a number

Test(d1) 'this will always go to Sub Routine 1 regardless of whether OPTION strict is ON or OFF
Test(d2) 'this will go to Sub Routine 1 if option strict is ON.  If it is OFF, then it may go to Sub Routine 2 depending on the size of the number.
```

Comment: I'm sorry.. i forgot to mention that option strict on is specified

Comment: @jvcoach23, can you post the code, which calls the functions?

Answer (score 0):

I was given a way to work with this by Viorel on another forum.  He suggested I do

```
Check(drow, "decWorkWeekHours", 0@)
```

and that did indeed work.  When i asked what it does, this was his response.

> With ‘@’, the constant ‘0@’ becomes a decimal one. Then VB.NET chooses the definition of Check that takes a Decimal parameter, since it is more suitable comparing with other candidates.
>   You can also write ‘0d’ [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/data-types/type-characters].

hope that will help someone else down the road.
Thanks
shannon